# Emulator comes up, but is very unstable

Tags: android

The emulator comes up but its very unstable. It keeps giving me the window that asks to send data to microsoft. The it becomes not responding and freezes up. Sometimes I might keep it up for a while and am not doing anything to it and all of a sudden it pops up the debug window.
Is there something I can do to make it more stable.

Comment: did you try updating adt plugin as well as android sdk??
Also try reinstalling

Comment: Thanks Gaurav and Richard for your reply. One thing I tried is increasing the SD card size to 512MiB and it has stayed good till now. Maybe that might have been the issue. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

This is specific to your system and the software installed on it.  The emulator is rock solid (mostly), so try and solve the problem on your system.

Comment: Borderline, but this should probably be a comment (because it can't be judged as 'correct' or 'incorrect')

Answer (score 0):

I had such problems when trying to create an emulator with higher resolutions. 
Creating a simpler device solved my problem. Probably it was due to my PC specs (P4 2.4 Ghz, 1 GB of RAM).

Answer (score 0):

I have found emulator instances and the AVD manager itself to be VERY flakey.

This is despite re-installs, constant SDK updates and across multiple machines.

Often the only resolution I've found is to delete the AVD that is crashing and recreate it from scratch.

Also make sure you are using the snapshot facility so that you are at least loading fast when it does crash.